# SOQL Query Like % Wild Card not working?

Tags: soql, user, user-record

I am currently trying to do a SOQL query with a like using the % wildcard.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm):

> The % wildcard matches zero or more characters.

This does not seem like it's working. For example:

```
SELECT
Id,
UserType 
FROM user
WHERE UserType like '%PowerPartner%'
```

Returns back 0 results

```
SELECT
Id,
UserType 
FROM user
WHERE UserType = 'PowerPartner'
```

Returns back 2 results

Is there something I am missing?

Now that I typed this all up, it has me thinking that the issue is due to the fact UserType is a picklist. Can you not use a like on a picklist field?

Comment: Normal picklist fields work with `LIKE`. That implies that UserType is not a normal picklist field. Whatever it actually is, SOQL doesn't treat it like a String.

Comment: May or may not be related but I had similar issue with `Sometext % moreText` in an SOQL returning results with a value of `Sometext and noText` - I think there is something going on with SOQL wildcards because that value should not have been returned IMHO.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I thought is was someText any number then moreText - so you are saying the moreText part is ignored? I do not use wildcards that often so this is good to know if that is the case

Comment: @Eric Oh, wait, I misread your comment. That does sound weird. Hmm, I'll have to research that.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Don't bother. I cannot replicate it I just know it was a weird result.....If I can replicate it I will post a question

Comment: @Halfwarr, I didn't have any issue running the like SOQL query for `'%Standard%'` or `%scOn%` (CsnOnly). However, I didn't have any PowerPartner users in the org. Is it only PowerPartner that is causing issues?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Correct  PowerPartner is the only one that is causing issues

Comment: @DanielBallinger Appears I was incorrect about it just being partner that is causing the problem check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some more research into the issue and it looks like it's a bug on the Salesforce side. Now I can only theorize on why it's happening.

The `UserType` field is a bit interesting it's a picklist that has labels and actual values according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm?search_text=user).

- Standard: user license. This user type also includes Salesforce
  Platform and Salesforce Platform One user licenses. Label is
  Standard.
- PowerPartner: User whose access is limited because he or she is a
  partner and typically accesses the application through a partner
  portal or community. Label is Partner.
- CSPLitePortal: user whose access is limited because he or she is an
  organization's customer and accesses the application through
  a Customer Portal or community. **Label is High Volume Portal**.
- CustomerSuccess: user whose access is limited because he or she is an
  organization's customer and accesses the application through a
  Customer Portal. Label is **Customer Portal User**.
- PowerCustomerSuccess: user whose access is limited because he or she
  is an organization's customer and accesses the application through a
  Customer Portal. Label is **Customer Portal Manager**.
- CsnOnly: user whose access to the application is limited to Chatter.
  This user type includes Chatter Free and Chatter moderator users.
  Label is **Chatter Free**.

I've tested this on some of the Values with Labels. It appears when doing a Like on a SOQL search it only checks the label.

Some Examples:

```
SELECT
Id,
UserType 
FROM user
WHERE UserType like '%Partner%'
```

Returns results back

```
SELECT
id,
userType
from
user
WHERE UserType like '%PowerCustomerSuccess%'
```

Returns no results back

```
SELECT
id,
userType
from
user
WHERE UserType like '%Customer Portal Manager%'
```

Returns results back

The above tests seems to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Odd, as I was able to SOQL for `%scOn%` without issue and it found the CsnOnly records.